# Linux/Bash: How to unquote?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, arguments

Following command

```
echo 'a b' 'c'
```

outputs

```
a b c
```

But the following

```
X="'a b' 'c'"
echo $X;
```

will outout

```
'a b' 'c'
```

I am searching a way to unquote $X , so that it will output "a b c" , but without losing the merged 'a b' argument. (= 2 arguments instead of 3, makes no difference for command 'echo', but for other commands like 'cp')

Comment: echo ${X//\'/}; // a b c

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try xargs:

```
$ echo $x
'a b' 'c'

$ echo $x | xargs ./echo
argc = 3
argv[0] = ./echo
argv[1] = a b
argv[2] = c
```

Comment: Note: xargs cannot return the exit status of the process. Any error 1-125 will be shown as 123. (Probably no workaround available) I will probably use eval instead, to be able to use the exitcode

Comment: This answer helped me, but I did not get it at first.

Here is what I used:
`echo $x | xargs -n1 echo`

output:
a b
c

Answer (score 8):

```
eval echo $x
```

this will pass `a b` as first argument and `c` as the second one

Note: this will actually evaluate arguments, eg:

```
$ x='$((3+5))'
$ eval echo $x
8
```

If that's not what you want use @vanza's `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't yet used "eval", but it seems that xargs is safer according to script-injections.

Comment: "eval" is a dangerous sledge-hammer tool so should be used VERY judiciously if at all.  What happens when some nefarious type appends ';rm -rf ~" or perhaps "; sudo rm /"  to your eval string ?  No!  Bash&(other-shells) *should*   have a feature to expand strings w/ ZERO side effects to the non-shell environment.  This likely means that command substitution is more restrictive - but that's fine IMO

Answer (score 3):

Usually, if you're trying to store multiple "words" in a single variable, the recommended method isn't to use embedded quotes, but to use an array:

```
X=('a b' 'c')
printf "%s\n" "${X[@]}"
```

prints:

```
a b
c
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use eval for something like this. `set` will keep the integrity of the parameters and commands other than `echo` will play nicely with them. Just keep in mind you'll lose the reference(s) to any current positional parameters.

```
set -- "a b" "c"
echo "$@"
#a b c
echo $1
#a b
echo $2
#c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X="'a b' 'c'"
echo $X
eval "echo $X"
```

When you use this code you have to be careful if `X` can possibly contain special characters like `\"$` or backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `echo` receives a 2 parameters in `echo $X` ?  For me, it receives 3.  Lets try:

```
X="'a b' 'c'"
function f(){ echo $#; echo $1; echo $2; echo $3; }
f $X
```

displays:

```
3
'a
b'
'c'
```

The 3 parameters are `'a`, `b'` and `'c'`.  I do not think it is what you expect.

If you want to build a multi parameter variable, set IFS to a char you will not use (maybe `|`), and use it as a parameter delimiter in your variable:

```
X="a b|c"
IFS="|"
function f(){ echo $#; echo $1; echo $2; }
f $X
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to combine `xargs` and `sh -c 'cmd' _ arg1 arg2 ...` to reparse arguments into the positional parameter array `$@`.

Assigning the output to a variable and redirecting anything but the exit status `$?` of the last process to `stderr`, for example, makes it possible to store the exit code of the last process in a variable and use it after `xargs` has ended execution.

```
X="'a b' 'c'"

ret="$(
export IFS=''
set -o pipefail
echo $X | xargs sh -c '
   for file in "$@"; do
      echo cp "$file" destdir 1>&2 || { echo $?; kill -HUP $PPID; exit $?; } 
      #(exit 3) || { echo $?; kill -HUP $PPID; exit $?; }
      #(exit 3) || { echo $?; kill -HUP $PPID; kill -HUP -- -$$; }
  done
  echo $?
' _
echo $? '|' ${PIPESTATUS[@]} 1>&2
)"
echo "$ret" | tail -1
```

Answer (score -1):

This is hairy, I'd recommend working around the issue and don't concatenate "a b" and "c" in the first place.