# curl command on linux break json text and get backslashes

Tags: linux, json, curl

I am having some issues with curl command. For example

```
$ curl --connect-timeout 2000  -v -X POST ....
* About to connect() to ************************
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to ********************
> POST ********************** HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.12.9.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
> Host: ******
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 92
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< ****************:
< X-b: **************
< X-a: ***************
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 8228
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26)


....
\"f1\":\"v1\"},\"f2\":{\"f3\":false},\"f4\":\"v4\",\"f5\":fa* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
lse,\"f6\":25}}"}}
```

Notice, the problems are:

- The json got quoted with `\`
- the content with broken by `Connection #0 to host localhost left intact Closing connection #0`

My question is: how to get rid of these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message occurs, because you probably join standard output and standard error. Try to redirect standard error:

```
curl 2>/dev/null
```

In order to unqoute the string see here: [Linux/Bash: How to unquote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988288/linux-bash-how-to-unquote)